# Conditions on a measure

Tags: measure-theory, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Suppose we have a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R_+$ such that $\forall s>0$ $t^s\in L^1(\mathrm d\mu(t))$, but functions $\mathbf{1}_{t>0} $ and $\mathbf{1}_{t\in (0,1)}$ are not necessarily in $L^1(\mathrm d\mu(t))$.

I'd like to impose some conditions on $\mu$ so the function

$$f:p\to \frac{\int_0^\infty t^p \mathrm d\mu(t)}{\int_0^\infty t^{p-1}\mathrm d\mu(t) },\quad p>1 $$
is monotone on $(1,\infty)$. For example, if $\mathrm d\mu(t)=e^{-t}\mathrm d t $, then $f(p)=p$. Another example is $\mathrm d\mu(t)= \mathbf{1}_{t\in (0,1)}\mathrm d t $, $f(p)=p/(p+1)$ (monotone, too).

Somehow this reminds me the [Riesz–Thorin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem), but I don't see how I can apply it here.

Are there any results on this (or similar) subject? What are possible ways to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of leaving an answer here, I'll post an idea of proof suggested by Mateusz Wasilewski at Mathoverflow( [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134511/conditions-on-a-measure-to-satisfy-certain-relation-on-moments)): in fact, the result quickly follows from log-convexity of the application $p\to\int_{0}^\infty t^p\mathrm d\mu(t)$ (it can be established by Hölder inequality).